# How to retrieve email from GMail account using PHP?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm trying to automatically retrieve some email from my GMail account for further parsing, but I can't get my head around on how to do that. I've searched the internets and it suggested that I use PHP's `imap` functions, like this:

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$connection = imap_open($server, 'my.name@gmail.com', 'password');
```

But using that code, I get:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any server setting that might be preventing me from making a connection to GMail (I'm using a shared service)? Is the address even right? Has anyone ever managed to do something like this? I've found tons of examples on how to *send* email via GMail, but very little of retrieving.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use Google API for that

Comment: The Google API seems to always require some kind of manual intervention to fetch data, which I'm trying to avoid. Will look into that, though.

Comment: It has two modes as far as i know. First one using token from their site and other one is your own authentication which you can use to avoid manual intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my host's configuration, apparently outgoing connections to port 993 were prevented.

Answer (score 1):

That worked fine for me (Your exact code, with my u/p).  Are you sure you have IMAP turned on in your GMail account (In your account settings)?  I used 5.3.2 on Linux (CentOS)...